# About creating a View With additional coumns (that are not in the table)

Tags: db2, view

I have this view with following definition.

```
create view VIEW_IRS1 as Select 
MBR.PRSN_MBRSH_ID
, Atr.Ssn_Tx
, Names.First_Na
, Names.Middle_Na
, Names.Last_Na
, Reff.Ref_Cd_Desc_Tx Suffix_Na
,'FALSE' AS [Request Title II Monthly Income Verification]

From Hix.T_Enrt En 
Inner Join Hix.T_Prsn_Enrt Pe On En.Enrt_Id = Pe.Enrt_Id And En.Enrt_Status_Cd In (428,439, 430 ) And Pe.Active_In = 'Y' And (Pe.Retro_In Is Null Or Pe.Retro_In = 'N') 

Left Outer Join Hix.T_Aptc Ap On En.Enrt_Id = Ap.Enrt_Id

Left Outer Join Hix.T_Prsn_Addl_Attr Atr On Pe.Prsn_Mbrsh_Id = Atr.Prsn_Mbrsh_Id

Left Outer Join
(                   
    Select nAc.Prsn_mbrsh_Id,  First_Na , Middle_Na , Last_Na, Suffix_Cd From Hix.T_Prsn_Name Na, Hix.t_prsn_mbrsh_prsn_name_ac nAc
    where na.prsn_name_id = nAc.prsn_Name_Id
) Names On Pe.prsn_mbrsh_id = Names.prsn_mbrsh_id

Left Outer Join Hix.T_Ref_Data Reff On Names.Suffix_Cd = Reff.Ref_Data_Id

Left Outer Join Hix.T_Ref_Data Re On Atr.GENDER_CD = Reff.Ref_Data_Id

Left Outer Join Hix.T_PRSN_MBRSH MBR on MBR.PRSN_MBRSH_ID=Pe.PRSN_ENRT_ID;
```

I want to create a new view (not alter this view) with an additional column name say "ABC" whose value should always be FALSE. How can I do that?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you not just create a new view that is

```
SELECT *, 0 AS "ABC"
FROM VIEW_IRS1
```

Or if you mean the text 'False'

```
SELECT *, 'FALSE' AS "ABC"
FROM VIEW_IRS1
```

Or to edit the existing view:

```
SELECT 
    MBR.PRSN_MBRSH_ID
    , Atr.Ssn_Tx
    , Names.First_Na
    , Names.Middle_Na
    , Names.Last_Na
    , Reff.Ref_Cd_Desc_Tx Suffix_Na
    , 'FALSE' AS "My Really Long Name"
FROM 
    AllYourOtherTables
```